# How to replace a string by searching through regular expression in twig?

Tags: jquery, html, css, regex, twig

I want to replace special characters and white space with _(underscore) character in twig, but I am not getting on how to replace that. Can I do it without including any external library?
Here's my code-

```
{% set special_characters='!@#$%^*()' %}
{{ special_characters|replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/','_') }}
```

Comment: You should write a custom filter. Here's an example:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35602077/how-to-perform-regex-using-twig

Comment: Is this for making pretty urls? If so, please consider using some library to generate slugs, instead of doing it on your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Sluibaren's right, you should write a custom filter, but if you want to do it in twig, you can do something like that:

```
{% set special_characters='!@#$%^*() '|split('') %}

{% set your_string = 'Hello!your@string#has $many%specials^characters*in(this)exemple'|split('') %}

{% set your_new_string = "" %}

{% for char in your_string %}
  {% if (char in special_characters) %}
    {% set your_new_string = your_new_string ~ '_' %}
  {% else %}
    {% set your_new_string = your_new_string ~ char %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{{ your_new_string }}
```